# Relating issues in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

The Gitlab documentation ([here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/related_issues.html)) says you can click the "+" to add related issues. But where is this "+" on the called "header of the related issue block"? Is it a restricted feature?

My issues in my private projects do not have this "+" on the header as this sample picture from documentation shows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think documentation has missing information about this feature. I've found below explanation

> .. Related issues is a feature that would only be available for public projects or private projects in a group or namespace with at least the Bronze plan applied. ..

at [here.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/3325) We have all private projects and there is no visible *"add related issue"* button.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more with [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#shortcut-to-open-related-issue) (March 2022):

> ### Shortcut to open related issue
>
> When creating a new issue from another issue, an option to mark the two issues as related is selected by default.
>
> This handy shortcut enables you to create one or more related issues without having to remember or copy-pasting issue IDs.
>
> Thanks for the contribution [Steve](https://gitlab.com/smokris)!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_9/shortcut_to_open_related_issue.gif -- Shortcut to open related issue]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#from-another-issue-or-incident) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/198494).